# Laravel 5.2: Flash has no defined hint path

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am attempting to create a view after installing the `"laracasts/flash": "^1.3"} package, and this is my code:

```
@include('gazett.errors')
```

The following code is found in the blade.php file in 'gazett.errors':

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-7 col-md-push-3" style="padding: 5px 24px!important;">
    @include('flash::message')
    @if($errors->any())
        <ul class="alert alert-danger text-center rtl ur fsize26" style="list-style: none;">
            @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                <li style="color: #000 !important;"> {{ $error }} </li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    @endif
</div>
```

But I get the following error: There is no hint path defined for flash message.

My directory structure is shown in the link [Directory Structure].[1](http://prntscr.com/a6vnuy)
When I go to browser, I get the following error:

```
ErrorException in FileViewFinder.php line 112:
```

No hint path defined for [flash]. (View: E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\wifaq-atropos\resources\views\gazett\errors.blade.php) (View: E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\wifaq-atropos\resources\views\gazett\errors.blade.php) (View: E:\Web\xampp\htdocs\wifaq-atropos\resources\views\gazett\errors.blade.php)

This problem appeared when I attempted to upgrade Laravel from 5.0 to 5.2. There was no error in the previous project 5.0 version. How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

And then, if using Laravel 5, include the service provider within config/app.php.

```
'providers' => [
    'Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider'
];
```

Comment: laravel 5.4 - same

Answer (score 6):

I had similar error when using larvael 5.2, here is how i resolved it.

Include this service provider within config/app.php of your project

```
'providers' => [
        Laracasts\Flash\FlashServiceProvider::class,];
```

On the same file look for aliases; add this line

```
'aliases' => [  'Flash' => Laracasts\Flash\Flash::class, ]
```

The above addition to config/app.php makes @include('flash::message') in my view to work fine

Answer (score 0):

you can set it manually

if you have your blades views in ...views/flash, that is how you can specify it:

```
app('flash')->addNamespace('mail', resource_path('views') . '/flash');
```