# How to define a hint path for laravel blades

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-blade

If you go into an error blade file for example `403.blade`, you will see it uses construction like:

```
@extends('errors::layout')
```

I would like to use the same construction or at least understand how it works.

so I'm trying from a controller

```
return view('role::account.list');
```

and getting exception

```
 No hint path defined for [role].
```

I knew it was not defined, but how can I define it?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35575891/laravel-5-2-no-hint-path-defined-for-flash

Comment: @Metalik, thank you for your link, please check out my answer, you may be interested in this dark sorcery.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest way is to use a ServiceProvider and a `loadViewsFrom` call:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/packages#views

```
/**
 * Perform post-registration booting of services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/path/to/views', 'courier');
}
```

Will allow you to use view namespace courier:

```
Route::get('admin', function () {
    return view('courier::admin');
});
```

You can also use the logic that is running behind the scenes, by using the View factory which uses the FileViewFinder:

```
app('view')->addNamespace('role', resource_path('views/role'));
```

There are more methods available either via the Factory of via the FileViewFinder, you can retrieve the finder like this:

```
app('view')->getFinder();
```

Comment: Thank you. I choose solution number two. :)

Answer (score 1):

Add hint path like so:

```
app('view')->addNamespace('role', config('view.paths')[0].'/roles/visitor');
```

you can do it in a controller or Middleware.

And If you want to change it later just do this:

```
app('view')->replaceNamespace('role', resource_path('views') . Auth::user()->role->view_path);
```

Yes it is ridiculous that the error says "hint path" and a function named "addNamespace".
And it is upsetting that this is NOT a part of documentation.

Answer (score 0):

On `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file:

```php
// boot method:
public function boot(Dispatcher $events)
{
    //...
    $this->loadViewsFrom(\resource_path('views/tiago'), 'TIAGO');
}

/*
Using your file 
resources/views/tiago/basic.blade.php
*/

// Using:
Route::get('basic', fn () => view('TIAGO::basic'));
```